# Auto-delete messages in MySQL database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hi I have a MySQL database table where a user inputs messages (via a form) and I was wondering if there is a way to automatically delete a message after say 1 minute has passed?
The code i'm using is PHP.
Thanks very, very much for any replies :)

Comment: What's your table schema look like?

Comment: what kind of server Os are you running?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could always run a delete query before you do anything else. For example whenever you check for messages, first delete all messages older than 1 minute.

I think I would rather just not get the messages older than 1 minute though. It can be nice with a log :)

Comment: I agree entirely with not deleting them. There are very few items that ever get deleted from my databases, they are usually just deactivated

Comment: Thanks I really do need to delete them to stop the database getting too full...the first suggestion 'You could always run a delete query before you do anything else. For example whenever you check for messages, first delete all messages older than 1 minute.' will work...so obvious don't know why i didn't think of that doh!
thanks that's brill :)

Answer (score 4):

I can think of two ways to achieve that.

1. Make a script to run every X minutes and make any changes in your db.
2. Delete all expired records before or after inserting new records in your script.

Comment: Deleting in relation to insertion won't help anything.

Comment: That's not what I meant to say. I'll revise.

Comment: I think the second bullet of this answer is the direct answer to the queston. You can delete the expired records whenever the page is recalled. So this way you do not need to setup a cron job. Lean solution. That said, I agree with the `do not delete` answers. In my experience, deleting is a big burden on tables.

Answer (score 2):

When a message is inserted to the DB, store a time_created timestamp. Then in your PHP, you only display messages whose timestamp falls within 1 minute of the current time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cron job to purge old messages.

Answer (score 1):

- You could make a cron script to run every minute and delete all old messages
- or make a valid_until column in your table, and set it to NOW()+60 - then only show rows which have valid_until >= NOW().

Answer (score 1):

Building a cron service is the first thing that pops into my mind, although is probably an unnecessary complication.

You can call the delete in the same script that does the insert after a [sleep](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) of 1 minute.

```
 sleep ($seconds);
 // call the delete query
```

Another way is to pass the delay logic to a Mysql [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) that will do the delete for you.

```
SELECT SLEEP(<seconds>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: user cron job which runs every minute to check and delete

Solution 2: use ajax do that job

I personally suggest the first solution but if u have no SSH access to the server u have to choose the second one :D

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the replies/help :) the first suggestion by Svish 'You could always run a delete query before you do anything else. For example whenever you check for messages, first delete all messages older than 1 minute.' will work...so obvious don't know why i didn't think of that doh! Thanks again every1.